# For $f : X \rightarrow Y$ a morphism of schemes, for $U \subset X$ a nonempty affine open, must $f(U)$ be contained in some affine open of $Y$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes

Is there a morphism of schemes $f : X \rightarrow Y$ admitting a nonempty affine open $U \subset X$
such that $f(U)$ is not contained in any affine open of $Y$?

Clearly if such $f$ and $U$ exist then $Y$ must be a non-affine scheme.
However I'm not sure how to proceed further than this. Would anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Let $V \subset Y$ be affine and meeting (set-theoretically) $f(X)$. Then $f^{-1}(V)$ contains a non-empty affine open subset $U$ of $X$ (because it’s an open subset of $X$). Then $f(U) \subset V$ with $U,V$ affine.

Comment: @Aphelli Sorry I've edited my question now, I'm looking for an example of f and nonempty affine open U with f(U) not contained in any affine open.

Comment: Jouanolou's trick shows that any quasi-projective variety is covered by a torsor under a vector bundle, whose total space is affine. So if you apply this construction to a projective variety, you get an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends what conditions you want to add... for instance take $\Bbb{P}^1$ over a field $k$ and note that there is a covering $\Bbb{A}^1_k \sqcup \mathrm{Spec}\:k \to \Bbb{P}^1$. Now, $\Bbb{A}^1_k \sqcup \mathrm{Spec}\: k = \mathrm{Spec}(k[x] \times k)$. The image under the obvious surjective map $\Bbb{A}^1_k \sqcup \mathrm{Spec}\:k\to \Bbb{P}^1$ is all of $\Bbb{P}^1$ and hence not contained in any affine open.

Comment: Hm I see, thanks very much!